# Can I set the Utilities panel in Xcode 4 to open by default on all new projects?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I'm currently learning iOS development from scratch, and as such, I'm making lots of new projects. Every time I do so, I have to resize the Xcode window (I don't want it maximised, but I don't want it as tiny as it makes it), and I also have to pop open the Utilies and Debug areas, as well as dragging the Objects library up to make it larger. Can I set some defaults in Xcode to do this for every new project?

Answer (score 1):

No, Xcode doesn't include all these options, but you can get part way there. You can setup a behavior that shows or hides the parts of an Xcode window such as the utilities, the toolbar, the debugger, etc. Then it's one menu selection or key command to show the parts, and a little dragging to resize things.

To make a behavior select Behaviors>Edit Behaviors... from the "Xcode" menu in Xcode. Create a new behavior by clicking the "+" symbol near the lower left corner. Give your behavior a name and optionally a key command. Set the options in the behavior to show or hide the parts you want shown or hidden, and maybe even take some of the other available actions.

To run the behavior just select it from the "Behaviors" submenu of the "Xcode" menu, or press the appropriate key command combination.